# send the values of ckeditor using ajax it diaplays only few lines

Tags: php, ajax, ckeditor

ckeditor contents will completely get in script.i can check this via alert.

```
var ckpost=CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();
alert(ckpost);
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "addpost.php",  
        data: "ckpost=" + ckpost,  
        success: function(msg){  }
});
```

[image]

after this alert i am send the values of ckpost to another page using ajax.but in my addpost.php i can get only few lines of this ckpost.

[image]

```
$post =$_POST['ckpost'];
echo $post;
```

These codes are used in my addpost.php.How can i get these complete values usingajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    var ckpost=CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "addpost.php",  
        data: "ckpost=" + encodeURIComponent(ckpost),  
        success: function(msg){  }
    });
</script>
```

**addpost.php**

```
<?php
$ckpost = decodeURIComponent($_POST['ckpost']);
.
.
?>
```

**encodeURIComponent**

> encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except the following:
>   alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ).  The
>   encodeURIComponent() function encodes a URI component. This function
>   encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the following
>   characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

*Syntax* :

> encodeURIComponent(str);

**decodeURIComponent**

> The decodeURIComponent() function decodes a URI component.

*Syntax* :

> decodeURIComponent(uri);

For more info, [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) & [decodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Your request data is not properly encoded, you can use encodeURIComponent

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "addpost.php",  
        data: "ckpost=" + encodeURIComponent(ckpost),  
        success: function(msg){  }
});
```

or pass an object as the data parameter

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "addpost.php",  
        data: {"ckpost": ckpost},  
        success: function(msg){  }
});
```

to have the request be properly encoded.

Comment: @musa..its works fine.what is the use for encodeURIComponent.can you explain?

Comment: Lets say your ckpost variable was "The CEO of S&J Ltd", then `"ckpost=" + ckpost` will give you `ckpost=The CEO of S&J Ltd`. The `&` acts as a parameter separator so `J Ltd` will be treated as a second parameter rather than data. With `encodeURIComponent` the `&` will be encoded to `%26` so you have `ckpost=The CEO of S%26J Ltd`. After the parameters are read they will be decoded and you will get the full text for ckpost.